# What is the query format for "< string > array(csv)" schema in Keycloak Admin API?

Tags: url, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

In Keycloak Admin REST API, I am trying to perform `GET /{realm}/events` request for getting events by realm.

In the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) it says to filter by type of event you add the query param `< string > array(csv)`. However that schema is not exactly clear, for example how to get both `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT` events?

So far I have tried formats like `?type=LOGIN,LOGOUT` and `?type='LOGIN','LOGOUT'` but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who faced this situation, after several trials and looking through the Keycloak source code I found out that what is meant by `< string > array(csv)` is to add the query like this: `?type=LOGIN&type=LOGOUT`.